# Magento - Product Prices index process error

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've tried to do the following thus far to fix my issues with the product prices indexer (being run through SSH)...

- Use the Magento database repair tool
- Disable extensions related to pricing modifications
- MySQL Repair

Still, I get the following error:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#5 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#6 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(455): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `mg...')
#7 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(379): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareTierPriceIndex()
#8 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/apndev/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/apndev/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#4 /home/apndev/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#5 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(455): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `mg...')
#6 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(379): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareTierPriceIndex()
#7 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#8 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#9 /home/apndev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#10 /home/apndev/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#11 /home/apndev/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#12 {main}
```

I'm running Magento 1.7 and the reason I'm pressing to have this done is that I see some 'special pricing' locked in on the front end. In other words, prices are showing as 'special prices' simply because the pricing changed at one point.

Thanks!

Comment: try to run `Product Flat Data` index first after that try to run `Product Price` index.

Comment: did you upgraded your magento from old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.try to remove var/locks/*

2.php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall